# GoでSprintfの使い方

Tags: go

Goの`Sprintf`を使って曖昧検索をするための`%namae%`のような文字列は作れますか。

`name := fmt.Sprintf("%%s%", object.Name)`
のような記述をしたところ
`%s%!(NOVERB)%!(EXTRA string=namae)`
という文字列が生成されました。試しに最初と最後の%を`\`でエスケープしましたがエラーが出てできませんでした。

Comment: `name := fmt.Sprintf("%%%s%%", object.Name)` の様に `%` を2つ重ねて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます! できました。